# ng build --production does not fully uglify js classes

Tags: angular-cli

When creating a production angular 14 build the output javascript bundles seem to be minified and uglified, but not to the extent that I was expecting.

When looking into the outputted files in the dist folder, parts of the file are indeed minified and uglified. Other parts of the file are in plain javascript and expose quite a lot about the application.

I have attached an example whereby one can clearly read the app component in the main bundle after being minified and uglified. I would have expected this code to have been obfuscated too.

What would really be useful to know is if there is a setting to minify the classes too or if not, is there a way to customise the angular cli build process to achieve the complete type of obfuscation I initially expected ?

[image]

As requested here is the anglar.json file

```js
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
"minification-testing": {
  "projectType": "application",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "style": "scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:application": {
      "strict": true
    }
  },
  "root": "",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "prefix": "app",
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/minification-testing",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": []
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "optimization": true,
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "500kb",
              "maximumError": "1mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "2kb",
              "maximumError": "4kb"
            }
          ],
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "outputHashing": "all"
        },
        "development": {
          "buildOptimizer": false,
          "optimization": false,
          "vendorChunk": true,
          "extractLicenses": false,
          "sourceMap": true,
          "namedChunks": true
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "production"
    },
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "minification-testing:build:production"
        },
        "development": {
          "browserTarget": "minification-testing:build:development"
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "development"
    },
    "extract-i18n": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "minification-testing:build"
      }
    },
    "test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
      "options": {
        "main": "src/test.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
        "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
        "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": []
      }
    }
  }
}
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have enabled `production: true` in the environment file?

Comment: Please give your `angular.json` ( or `angular-cli.json`) file too.

Comment: Added angular json. Yes the env file has production true